# stl vector of vectors conversion from double to unsigned int

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl, double

I'm trying to declare a vector of vectors with STL template class vector, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
int K = 4;
int clusterSize = 45;    
vector<vector<double> > clusters(K+1,vector<double>(clusterSize));
```

It throws me this error:

```
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I get no errors or warnings with g++ 4.8.1 using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: *"It throws me this error: warning C4244: ..."* Then read the message again, it is a **warning.**

Comment: Everything is declared right. Are you sure warning is for this line? Warning is not an error. It can work.

Comment: The code as presented looks fine. Could you wrap this code in a `main()` function that also presents this warning? My attempt at doing that has come up with no warnings: http://ideone.com/HvcnAK

Comment: No errors under VS2013 or GCC 4.7.2. Which compiler are you using? Are you sure the error relates to the block of code you've supplied?

Comment: I know this is a warning, I'm just trying to understand why the code is throwing me that warning. I use VS2012 with warnings on Level4(/W4) and treating warning as errors. It's a good way to be totally sure about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiled with C++Builder XE3, Windows 64-bit compiler, based on Clang 3.1, there are two warnings, but stating the same information: `implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')`.  The warnings are at the `K+1` and `clusterSize` locations in the declaration of `clusters`.

Whatever compiler is being used is trying to convey something similar about how an `int` is used instead of `size_type`.  Review this excellent vector reference for more constructor details: [std::vector::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would like to vote up your answer but I'm a newbie haha ;).
As I was saying on the comments, I put this answer here just to understand the code from the base. Thanks for giving me that info. I was looking at the reference contructor but I was not able to find it.

Comment: @joscormir You are welcome.  There are so many constructors within the Standard Library (SL) containers.  Some take `size_type` arguments and others do not.  I have not yet found a SL container constructor that takes an `int` though.  The `cppreference` site is an excellent resource.